# Google People API - get contact details (batch)

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

Using [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts), one can get a contact detail by its ID.

```
"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/" + id + "?key=" + <KEY> + "&personFields=addresses,clientData,emailAddresses,names,organizations,phoneNumbers,birthdays",
```

Is it possible to get such details in batch? I have a list of 100 contact ids and I want them to get at once as it'd be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the method of "Method: people.getBatchGet"? When this method is used, the 200 resource names (maximum number) can be retrieved by one API call. When this is used for your situation, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl \
  'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet?personFields=addresses%2CclientData%2CemailAddresses%2Cnames%2Corganizations%2CphoneNumbers%2Cbirthdays&resourceNames=people%2Fsample1&resourceNames=people%2Fsample2&resourceNames=people%2Fsample3' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

- In above case, the unencoded endpoint is `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:batchGet?personFields=addresses,clientData,emailAddresses,names,organizations,phoneNumbers,birthdays&resourceNames=people/sample1&resourceNames=people/sample2&resourceNames=people/sample3`.
- Also, you can test this with "Try this API". [Ref](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet)